# Titanium: handle back button event on textfield

Tags: android, titanium, back-button

### Problem

I would like to handle the back button on textfield using titanium.

I know there is an event android:back on window but it does not fire on textfield.

How can I handle the back button (or the keyboard hide event) on a textfield using titanium ?

EDIT: here is some code and clarification to illustrate what I want to say:

### Step to reproduce :

1. click the textfield > focus event is fired, the keyboard is shown
2. hit back button >  the keyboard is hidden but the blur event is not called and the textfield hasn't lost the focus

### Code:

```
var textfield = Ti.UI.createTextfield();
textfield.addEventListener('android:back', function() {
  // this method is never called, so this event does not run on textfield
});

textfield.addEventListener('focus', function() {
  // this method is called at step 1
});

textfield.addEventListener('blur', function() {
  // this method is not called at step 2 because 
  // the back button only hide the keyboard but the focus is not lost
});

// what code should I use to catch event when the keyboard is hidden 
// when pressing the back button ?
```

Answer (score 0):

The `blur` event is fired whenever the keyboard is closed. [Here is the doc for it.](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/api/Titanium.UI.TextField-event-blur)

You can listen to it pretty easily, assuming you created a `textField` object of type `Titanium.UI.TextField`:

```
textField.addEventListener('blur', function(e) {
    var val = e.value; // Get current value when the keyboard closed (the right way) as opposed to textField.value (the wrong way)
    alert("The text is : "+value);
});
```

If you want to listen for the `android:back` event you have to listen on the window.

```
var win = Ti.UI.currentWindow; 
win.addEventListener('android:back', function(e) {
    // do crazy things
});
```

According to the docs this should work, if not possibly a bug with Titanium?

Comment: Thanks but that's not so easy. When you hit the back button, the keyboard is hidden but the focus is not lost (thanks android...), so the blur event is not fired :(

Comment: You shouldn't be listening on the textfield for the `android:back` event. You should be listening on the window.

Comment: Yes, I tried that but the event is not fired when the keyboard is shown. When you press the back button, the keyboard is hidden but no event is fired (neither blur on textfield or android:back on window). Then, when a second tap is done, the event android:back on window is fired but I would like to avoid this second step.

Comment: When the keyboard is shown? That would be the `focus` event. I'm a little confused about what you're trying to accomplish. Maybe show some code?

Comment: I updated my post to clarify the problem. Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: This is a weird one. Seems that the first back button gets rid of the keyboard but does NOT fire the event. Then it fires the event :/